# three.js image texture rendered as color (loaded with ColladaLoader)

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping, collada

I am a three.js newbie. Started learning 2 days ago.

I drew a box on SketchUp, exported as collada file (.dae), loaded into a scene with three.js.

Now i'm trying to tile the object with texture(s) but i failed.

Trying to tile this texture:

[image]

Getting this instead:

[image]

And my code is:

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500 );
    camera.position.set(-6,1,-3);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // collada

    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( 'kutu.dae', function(collada) {
        var object = collada.scene;
        //object.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );
        object.position.set(.18, 0, -.70 );

        //var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff00ff});
        var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "desen.jpg" );
        texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            map: texture,
            transparent: false
        });

        console.log(material);

        object.traverse( function (child) {

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                //if(Math.random() < 0.5)
                //    child.material = material;
                //else
                    child.material = material;
            }
        });

        scene.add( object );
    });

    //

    //var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 20 );
    //scene.add( gridHelper );

    //

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc );
    scene.add( ambientLight );
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, -1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    //

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.enableZoom = false;
    controls.enablePan = false;

    //

    stats = new Stats();
    document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );

    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    stats.update();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Please help...

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with UVs of your geometry.

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) tells a vertex to map to a specific percentage-based location in your texture. The lower-left corner of your image is `(0, 0)`, and top-right is `(1, 1)`. If the UVs in your geometry do not map correctly to the image (for example, all zeroes), you will get bad results. Check that your Collada file is exporting the UV coordinates correctly.

Comment: At this moment as a newbie, i don't know how to check that uv mapping values. So i'v created a pastebin url. Can you check if anything is wrong? Thank you. https://pastebin.com/4Rq9xnYk

Comment: Your Collada data does not contain UV coordinates. You should also be seeing a warning in your browser console: `RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`. Because you have no UVs, it's defaulting them to `(0, 0)`, which is the lower-left pixel in your image. That means that one pixel is used for all vertices in your model, making it all one color.

Comment: No errors. I think i have to learn how to give UV info to the object right? :( Thank you.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thank you bro. I see now. Tried and tested and it worked! So, i have to set UV mapping every object i drew, got it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If possible, please write up your solution, post it as an answer, and accept your own answer. That will help future readers who may be having the same problem.

Comment: I was expecting you to do it :) Because you gave the info.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after we discuss in the comments above, i have decided to add my own answer / solution.

I strongly recommend you to read comments of the question first.

The problem is, there is no UV info given / attached in the exported model file.

You have to define it yourself using a 3d modelling program (3ds max, Maya, Blender etc.) or use the SketchUV plugin.